# ec2 enable su for user ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, su, pam

I am trying to enable `rstudio-server` login with `ubuntu` on `ec2`, but it fails.

I think it uses the same auth mechanism as `su`.

So I did

```
sudo passwd
su someotheruser
su ubuntu
```

But even though I know the password is right I can't auth as `ubuntu` with `su`. How can I fix this?

Ideally I'd like to leave `ssh` password login disabled.

EDIT: To be clear, I am trying to login as user `ubuntu`

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. Are you trying to become user `ubuntu` or `rstudio-server`? And from which use account are you trying to do this? Please clarify your question.

Comment: @mtak: From any other user account I guess